# Send a constant from server to client in meteorjs

Tags: meteor

Scenario: You want to put the build id in the footer of a meteor app. The client will need a reference to process.env.BUILD_ID from the server.

Common answer: Save it in a collection. On meteor start, save the current build id to a collection and load that on the client.

Problem with the common answer: What if you have multiple containers running? Say for instance you're using kube to update the version. You have version `abc` running, and then kube starts pushing up `def`. In the process of starting each `def` container, it sets the current version in the db to `def`. Yet the `abc` containers are still running. If you hit one of those containers, it will report `def` as the build id. Even though thats wrong. Additionally, what if the kube update fails, and you decide to cancel the push to the new version and keep the old containers running. Until the next container restart, youll be serving the `abc` content but telling the user its version `def`.

What would be the proper way to store a constant and match it on the client without lying about its true value?

Comment: If you put it in a collection (i.e. in mongodb and *not* in a container environment variable) it will reactively get pushed to all clients regardless of what container they are currently connected to. Each client will see the updated value at nearly the same time. If you want to see the version number on the container you're connected to then get it via a method call that gets the value of the environment variable!

Answer (score 0):

Meteor methods are the way to get data from the server (as opposed to the using publications to get from the database).  I recommend using ValidatedMethod for extra modularity and nicer validation.

Define the following method in your project and make sure it is imported to the server on server startup:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { ValidatedMethod } from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method';

const getAppVersion = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'getAppVersion',
  validate: null,
  run({}) {
    return process.env.BUILD_ID;
  },
});

export default getAppVersion;
```

Then in the frontend code:

```
import getAppVersion from '/imports/api/methods/getAppVersion.js';

getAppVersion.call({}, (err, res) => {
  if (res) setFooterVersion(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw it in a store:

```
// in store.js
export default const store = {
    buildId: '',
};


// then in buildId.js:
import store from './store';

Meteor.call('getBuildId', (res, err) => store.buildId = res);


// in someplace like server/methods.js:
Meteor.methods({
    'getBuildId'() {
         return process.env.BUILD_ID;
    },
});


// then, anywhere you need the build id:
import store from './store';

store.buildId; // outputs build id
```

If you need to make it reactive, you can make the `store` object a `ReactiveDict`, then put the `Meteor.call` part within `Tracker.autorun` for what you want it to react to. You can alternatively put it in something like a `setInterval` to run every 10 minutes or so. Of course, you can always store it in the db too -- but for your scenario, you can try to create an additional column like `kubeNode` and pass in the server id from kubernetes into the db, so when you call it again, you call it with a reference to the appropriate k8s node.